# [Deep Q-Network]How to exclude ops at auto-differential of Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to create a Deep Q-Network (DQN) similar to [Deepmind DQN3.0](https://github.com/deepmind/dqn) using Tensorflow, but I am having some difficulties. I think that the cause is TensorFlow's auto-differential approach.

Please see this pic. This is the architecture of DQN3.0.

[image: DQN architecture]

In supervised learning, in order to approximate the output of the network to the label, calculate the difference by the loss function, back propagate it, and update the parameters with the optimizer.

In DQN, the state that AI experienced in the past accumulated in memory is input to two neural networks of TergetNetwork and Network again, and the difference between the two networks is reflected in the Network.

The output of each network is not the probability that the total will be 1 but the expected value.
TergetNetwork's output will include the discount rate(gamma) and the reward earned at that time.

And, looking at the implementation of DQN 3.0 (lua + torch), it compares the outputs of the current network to the action selected at that time, and backward propagates the difference directly by the backward method.

```
function nql:getQUpdate(args)
    local s, a, r, s2, term, delta
    local q, q2, q2_max

    s = args.s
    a = args.a
    r = args.r
    s2 = args.s2
    term = args.term

    -- The order of calls to forward is a bit odd in order
    -- to avoid unnecessary calls (we only need 2).

    -- delta = r + (1-terminal) * gamma * max_a Q(s2, a) - Q(s, a)
    term = term:clone():float():mul(-1):add(1)

    local target_q_net
    if self.target_q then
        target_q_net = self.target_network
    else
        target_q_net = self.network
    end

    -- Compute max_a Q(s_2, a).
    q2_max = target_q_net:forward(s2):float():max(2)

    -- Compute q2 = (1-terminal) * gamma * max_a Q(s2, a)
    q2 = q2_max:clone():mul(self.discount):cmul(term)

    delta = r:clone():float()

    if self.rescale_r then
        delta:div(self.r_max)
    end
    delta:add(q2)

    -- q = Q(s,a)
    local q_all = self.network:forward(s):float()
    q = torch.FloatTensor(q_all:size(1))
    for i=1,q_all:size(1) do
        q[i] = q_all[i][a[i]]
    end
    delta:add(-1, q)

    if self.clip_delta then
        delta[delta:ge(self.clip_delta)] = self.clip_delta
        delta[delta:le(-self.clip_delta)] = -self.clip_delta
    end

    local targets = torch.zeros(self.minibatch_size, self.n_actions):float()
    for i=1,math.min(self.minibatch_size,a:size(1)) do
        targets[i][a[i]] = delta[i]
    end

    if self.gpu >= 0 then targets = targets:cuda() end

    return targets, delta, q2_max
end


function nql:qLearnMinibatch()
    -- Perform a minibatch Q-learning update:
    -- w += alpha * (r + gamma max Q(s2,a2) - Q(s,a)) * dQ(s,a)/dw
    assert(self.transitions:size() > self.minibatch_size)

    local s, a, r, s2, term = self.transitions:sample(self.minibatch_size)

    local targets, delta, q2_max = self:getQUpdate{s=s, a=a, r=r, s2=s2,
    term=term, update_qmax=true}

    -- zero gradients of parameters
    self.dw:zero()

    -- get new gradient
    self.network:backward(s, targets)
```

For this reason, if you do not mind the speed of the compute block in the above figure, you can calculate it by using Numpy etc. on the CPU instead of using Tensorflow, and I can exclude it from auto-differentiation I am thinking.

In DQN3.0, backpropagation is only computed only from output layer of *Network* (in blue). However, with my model in Tensorflow it starts from the final op `mul`.

I want to start backpropagation from that same output layer as in DQN3.0 using Tensorflow.

I understand that i can get `grads_and_vars` using compute_gradients() optimizer method, and run a manual differential process created from scratch. But, I think that implementing such a differential of convolution layer is very difficult to me.

Can I exclude compute block ops at auto-differential using Tensorflow functions or something? Or are there other methods to solve this?

Comment: Not exactly sure of what you're asking, but does [`tf.stop_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stop_gradient) help?

Comment: Thank you for comment.
I updated the pic, please see pic.
tf.stop_gradient() is using for excluding TargetNetwork.
But, I want to exclude only ops in red area.
My understanding that tf.stop_gradient() cannot.

Comment: I have edited your question for clarity, please see if this is what you are asking for. In addition, you are _heavily advised_ to write a [MCVE] of your neural network model in Tensorflow. In this case, it is important to know how you coded the full DQN model and how you're using the optimizer.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your editing and advice.
I would like to prepare about explicit examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all.

I solved the exclusion problem tentatively.

I created the original function which modified tf.gradients function as follows.

```
def gradients(ys,
          xs,
          grad_start, #***** ←Add arguments that new gradient start op ******
          grad_ys=None,
          name="gradients",
          colocate_gradients_with_ops=False,
          gate_gradients=False,
          aggregation_method=None):
              .
              .
              .
          # The set of 'from_ops'.
          stop_ops = _StopOps(from_ops, pending_count)
          while queue:
            # generate gradient subgraph for op.
            op = queue.popleft()
            with _maybe_colocate_with(op, colocate_gradients_with_ops):
              if loop_state:
                loop_state.EnterGradWhileContext(op, before=True)
              out_grads = _AggregatedGrads(grads, op, loop_state, aggregation_method)
              if loop_state:
                loop_state.ExitGradWhileContext(op, before=True)

              #*************************************************************
              # Add 2 line that replace 'out_grads' op to new grad start op
              if grad_start is not None and op == grad_start.op:
                  out_grads = ys
              .
              .
              .
```

As I confirmed it with Tensorboard, it looks like it is as expected.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG1e0.png

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not compatible with training your network.

The backpropagation starting point is your loss function (a.k.a the red block). In this loss function, all operations that can be differentiated will be, so that the gradient can "flow" throught the network. Every operations that you "exclude" from this process (using tf.stop_gradient for example) will be a stopping point for your backpropagation and the gradient will not flow to every values that your operation depends on.

Basically what does it mean? If you exclude the "compute block", you can't calculate any gradient for any of your variables.

Comment: Thank you for answer.I added it. Please check this.

Comment: I will try to explain it again : the red part is your loss function, excluding it from the auto-differential process makes no sense, you need it to train your variables! What you are asking is to write something like 'trainer.minimize(tf.stop_gradient(loss_function))' and still expect your network to train ! Whatever your problem is, it does not come from this !

Comment: Thank you comment agein.So why does DQN3.0 give higher performance than anyone without differentiating "loss function"?

Comment: It does differentiate a loss function! And in general, there is no neural network without a loss function to train it.

If you really want to make your implementation of DQN work, you should read carefully the research paper describing it. 

https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vmnih/docs/dqn.pdf

You should also familiarise yourself with the original Q-learning algorithme to understand the like between the original value function computation and the loss function.

Comment: It does differentiate a loss function!>As far as I see the implementation of torch it is not.

Comment: Also, it is said that using the DQN paper reads using mean square error, but the source of DQN 3.0 does not have it. Https://storage.googleapis.com/deepmind-media/dqn/DQNNaturePaper.pdf

Comment: The computation of the loss function is done in a few steps : first calculate the target value (done in 'getQUpdate(args)'), then calculate the gradient of the variables relative to the state and desired target, it is equivalent to doing 'yj − Q(φj , aj ; θ)' (done in 'backward(s, targets)'), then it is squared in the part of the code just below the last line you copied. The order is different, but the final result is the same as directly derivating the mean square error as it is more natural to do in tensorflow.

Comment: Yes it does provide an answer, the answer is what you request is not compatible with training your network.

Comment: @Arnaud - I fully agree with your point in the answer (that indeed OP is trying to achieve the unachievable, while the true solution is to pretty much do nothing), if you could however rewrite it as a statement, rather than a question, then probably Joe and other would not see an issue.

Comment: thank you all. I think that the opinion of @ Arnaud may be helping to find my understanding shortage. In that sense it may be a true "Answer". And, there was probably a new discovery. I did not know why DQN 3.0 implements its own RMSprop, but if @ Arnaud's opinion is correct, I understand its meaning.But @ Arnaud said that "it is squared" is about "self.tmp: sqrt ()" but I think that this is simply the square of RMSprop.If RMSprop is congruent with the mean square error, if we use the mean squared error function, we do not need to use RMSprop?

Comment: And the original two problems still remain unsolved: ① Tensorflow differentiates the red line area in the above figure, but does not do DQN 3.0. As a result, the contents of parameter update are different. ② If the implementation of DQM 3.0 is reproduced correctly in Tensorflow but the expression is different, why is DQN made with Tensorflow performance much lower than DQN 3.0? Or, if you have DQN implementation of Tensorflow that is equal to or higher than DQN 3.0, please present it.

Comment: The DQN paper shows its implementation with DQN 3.0 and uploaded it to github, and anyone can refer to it.
Also, github has many DQN implementations. Those authors say that they read and understand the paper (perhaps also referring to DQN 3.0). However, all the DQN implementations I have seen do hardly learn 'Breakout'.

Comment: My essential question is "Why can not Tensorflow get performance like DQN 3.0?"
I understand that @Arnaud understood it and wrote "Answer". That is a very grateful deed.